# sparql query with special characters

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to send a query through Ajax to dbperdia. It works fine but if the search term has special characters in it i get always an error message.

My code looks like

```
var IKS_QUERY = "PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> PREFIX resource: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX position:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> SELECT DISTINCT ?Abstract ?ThumbnailURL WHERE { resource:"+where+"  ontology:abstract  ?Abstract.  resource:"+where+" ontology:thumbnail ?ThumbnailURL. FILTER (lang(?Abstract)=\"en\")}";
var IKS_URL = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=" + escape(IKS_QUERY) + "&format=json";
```

and having special charactes in search term I get the following error message.

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 3: syntax error at ',' before '_Italy'

    SPARQL query:
    define sql:big-data-const 0 
    #output-format:application/sparql-results+json
    define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> PREFIX resource: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX position:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> SELECT DISTINCT ?Abstract ?ThumbnailURL WHERE { resource:Venice,_Italy  ontology:abstract  ?Abstract.  resource:wherePlaceHolder ontology:thumbnail ?ThumbnailURL. FILTER (lang(?Abstract)="en")}
```

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generated query is invalid, this has nothing to do with you sending it over AJAX.  Notice that the query in the Virtuoso error message has things like `resource:Venice,_Italy` which is illegal SPARQL syntax.

One workaround is to use full URIs here so instead of using building QNames as your current JS does you should build full URIs e.g.

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + where + ">
```

Instead of QNames like you do currently:

```
resource:" + where + "
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can you please help me how the following line will look like                                                                         var IKS_QUERY = "PREFIX ontology: &lt;http://dbpedia.org/ontology/&gt;  PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> PREFIX resource: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX position:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> SELECT DISTINCT ?Abstract ?ThumbnailURL WHERE { resource:"+where+"  ontology:abstract  ?Abstract.  resource:"+where+" ontology:thumbnail ?ThumbnailURL. FILTER (lang(?Abstract)=\"en\")}";

Comment: Just replace the `resource:" + where + "` bits with the alternative full URI form I showed in my answer